# RecyclerView inside ViewPager - scroll to last position shows only upper part of item view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.checkoins.app.checkoins.CountryTabActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And a Fragment with RecyclerView layout, that will be inflated into a viewpager from above:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_coin_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

When I use command:

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() -1)
```

it scrolls to that last item position, but displays only a PART of that item view, 
[image: Result - current behavior]

and I need to scroll by fingers to see that last item fully on screen.
[image: Desired behaviour]

How can I make it show the last item fully in code?

Comment: I would recommend adding a screenshot of current and expected behavior.

Comment: Edited and added images

Comment: Read the documentation. RecyclerView.scrollToPosition is a convenience method which calls RecyclerView.LayoutManager.scrollToPosition. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#scrollToPosition%28int%29

"Scroll to the specified position. Actual position of the item on the screen depends on the LayoutManager implementation." This means, you have in effect done what you set out to, you have scrolled and it is to that position. Now your next task is to take the view height and scroll by that amount to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line :

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a blank item at the last position. 
Below is how I do it.
**Step 1**:

```
static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View itemView;
    MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // the data is just what you'll then put into your recyclerview items
    return data == null ? 0 : data.size() + 1;
}
```

**Step 3:** This is also the last step.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // This statement must be placed in top of current method
    if(position == data.size) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }
}
```